# Fetch record greater than and less than from primary id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have lead table in which lead_id is primary id and i want to fetch the next lead_id and the previous lead_id in single query.Lead_id's are auto incremented but lead_id has a relationship with user. Is it possible to fetch data in single query?

Comment: post your code and attempts in the question

Comment: do you want to get prev lead_id and the next lead_id to a specific lead_id?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried already and try to clarify what you mean by previous and next lead_id (Are they current-1 and current+1 or do you mean the previous for the user and the next for the user where the user is the user for the current lead).  A clear question with exaples of what you have tried will get much better answers

Answer (score 1):

may be you can try something similar to this

```
(select lead_id from lead where lead_id < 4 order by lead_id DESC limit 1)    
union 
(select lead_id from lead where lead_id > 4 order by lead_id ASC limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from lead where 
      lead_id = (select min(lead_id) from lead where lead_id > 4) AND 
      lead_id = (select max(lead_id) from lead where lead_id < 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this code but should be something like the following where $lead_id is you php lead_id with a table named lead

`$query="SELECT * FROM lead WHERE lead_id =($lead_id+1) OR lead_id=($lead_id -1)";`

Comment: It wont work if `$lead_id = 3` & the next `lead_id = 5`. This condition may occur if `lead_id = 4` has been deleted.